# How to implement WKUIDelegate into SwiftUI WKWebView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I'm creating a web app on Xcode v11 and having a trouble implementing WKUIDelegate to display Javascript alert and confirm properly on the web app.

I got a very simple webview app with below code on ContentView.swift but not sure how to implement `WKUIDelegate` properly with this code.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Webview : UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    var webview: WKWebView?

    init(web: WKWebView?, req: URLRequest) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        self.request = req
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return webview!
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }

    func goBack(){
        webview?.goBack()
    }

    func goForward(){
        webview?.goForward()
    }

    func reload(){
        webview?.reload()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let webview = Webview(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            webview
            HStack() {
                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.goBack()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                }.padding(32)

                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.reload()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                }.padding(32)

                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.goForward()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                }.padding(32)
            }.frame(height: 32)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

What is the best way to implement `WKUIDelegate` into this code? So, it will display Javascript Alert and Confirm properly.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use `Coordinator` and then conform to `WKUIDelegate`:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, WKUIDelegate {
    var parent: Webview

    init(_ parent: Webview) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    // Delegate methods go here
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // alert functionality goes here
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}
```

Then ensure your `updateUIView(..)` sets the `uiDelegate` to the `context.coordinator`:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    uiView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
    [...]
}
```

> If you want to conform to `WKNavigationDelegate` then conform to it and set the `navigationDelegate` to the `context.coordinator` as well.

Full code here:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Webview : UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    var webview: WKWebView?

    init(web: WKWebView?, req: URLRequest) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        self.request = req
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKUIDelegate {
        var parent: Webview

        init(_ parent: Webview) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // Delegate methods go here

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            // alert functionality goes here
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return webview!
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        uiView.load(request)
    }

    func goBack(){
        webview?.goBack()
    }

    func goForward(){
        webview?.goForward()
    }

    func reload(){
        webview?.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Because I haven’t really used Swift before, I’m not sure how to implement your code to my existing code lol Can I add my code into where you have a comment “Code goes here”?

Comment: @Ohsik I updated the answer with the full code and where it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added your code but still not sure how to add alert functionality. My alert and confirm is controlled on the web app with Javascript. How will that interactive with Swift?

Comment: @Ohsik I recommend you accept this as the correct answer to your existing question and then ask a separate question with how to implement alert functionality.

Comment: Created a new question for the function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384352/implement-javascript-alert-and-confirm-on-wkuidelegate-swiftui

Comment: great answer! thanks for saving me some time ;-)