# Implement Javascript Alert and Confirm on WKUIDelegate SwiftUI?

Tags: javascript, swift, swiftui

Since I'm new to Swift, I'm not sure how to write a function for Swift to interactive Javascript Alert and Confirm from an Webapp. I'm creating an webapp with SwiftUI and need to implement a function for my Swift webapp to show Javascript Alert and Confirm properly from the webapp.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Webview : UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    var webview: WKWebView?

    init(web: WKWebView?, req: URLRequest) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        self.request = req
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKUIDelegate {
        var parent: Webview

        init(_ parent: Webview) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // Delegate methods go here

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            // alert functionality goes here

        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return webview!
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        uiView.load(request)
    }

    func goBack(){
        webview?.goBack()
    }

    func goForward(){
        webview?.goForward()
    }

    func reload(){
        webview?.reload()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let webview = Webview(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            webview
            HStack() {
                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.goBack()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                }.padding(32)

                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.reload()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                }.padding(32)

                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.goForward()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                }.padding(32)
            }.frame(height: 40)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

How can I add a function to show `Alert` and `Confirm` properly into my exiting code above?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `UIViewRepresentable` and use an alert from `UIKit` (such as `UIAlertController`) rather than SwiftUI’s Alert:

1. Create a function in your `Webview` struct to display a `UIKit` alert:

   ```
   func showAlert(_ message: String) {
      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
      alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

      // You need to access the UIWindow of the app to present the alert
      if let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController {
         viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
   }
   ```
2. Modify your JavaScript function to call this Swift function when showing an alert:

   ```
   function showAlert(message) {
      window.webkit.messageHandlers.alertHandler.postMessage(message);
   }
   ```
3. In the `userContentController(_:didReceive:)` method, call the `showAlert` function when you receive a message from JavaScript:

   ```
   func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
      if message.name == "alertHandler", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
         showAlert(messageBody)
      }
   }
   ```

When the JavaScript `function showAlert(message)` is called from your web page, it will trigger the `showAlert` function in your Webview struct, which will display a `UIKit` alert in your SwiftUI app using `UIAlertController`.